# Install specific version of chromium broswer on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, chromium

I installed the latest chromedriver (Version 92) with apt, however the broswer's version is 84.x.x and it prevents me from using selenium (`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 92 Current browser version is 84.0.4147.141`). I am relatively new to linux so any help on how should I proceed is very welcome.